# Excel vba - resize as date format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line in code:

```
.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(vef, 1), 1) = vef
```

Where `vef` is an array with data. Can I edit this line so it pastes `vef` in Date format `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: You have the array, you should easily be able to calculate your range. Can you not just set your range format prior to setting the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy enough. All you need to do is work with the same range and change the numberformat of the cells. Please note: the value being pasted is unchanged (and the values in your array should be dates). Excel applies a formatting so that what is displayed is changed, but without losing the underlying information.

If your array is full of strings, you will want to look at converting them to Dates beforehand. Excel may do this implicitly (e.g it may automatically format them, despite the original values being dates), but explicit conversion is preferred.

For your code, use this:

```
With .Range("D2").Resize(UBound(vef, 1), 1)
    .Value = vef
    .Numberformat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End With
```

Finally, I would just point out that your `Ubound(vef, 1)` will only work if your array is 1 based. If it is 0 based, your resized range will be off by 1. The formula you can use to find the length of a dimension in an array is:

```
Length = (Ubound(Array, DimensionNumber) - LBound(Array, DimensionNumber)) + 1
```

So in your case:

```
Length = (Ubound(vef, 1) - LBound(vef, 1)) + 1
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. I will take both things into consideration

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any other questions.